# VSCode writing for loops

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

This is doing my head in. It's just started happening in the last 24 hours. Why is 'await' the top option when inputting the variable name in a for loop?
How do I fix this so that it doesn't use await as the primary option for suggestions? I don't want to have to press escape every time I write the letter 'i' to prevent this stupid program changing my function to an async function with await in the middle of the for loop.

Intellisense messing me up

[image: Intellisense messing me up]

Comment: just keep on typing, the moment you type <space> the suggestion is gone

Comment: if you don't like VSC there are many other editors, free and paid, have a look at Emacs, Komodo

Comment: Just seems weird that it randomly began showing up. Not something I would have missed before since it's so jarring. Thanks though - had to disable the spacebar with editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter , since it was accepting on space.

Comment: AFAIK only Tab and Enter are accept keys and you can change a setting which is enabled/disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's really no fix to this.

You can, however, edit `settings.json`, and disable the spacebar with the following key.

```json
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter"
```

This should stop `await` from being accepted on a space action.